# How to write an appropriate test for backpack admin crud functionality?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I've implemented a laravel project which involves backpack admin, now I want to know is there any appropriate way to test its CRUD functionality (like the store, delete, etc actions)?

It doesn't matter what kind of test is needed (functional or unit test), I just want to test its functionality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way I found was to create browser tests using Laravel Dusk - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk